# User input via config file while building a deb package

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am trying to build a deb package and need user input for some configuration. I have used debconf to take user input as shown below.

templates file in DEBIAN/ directory-

```
Template: gateway/input1
Type: string
Description: MAC ID to be configured for the Gateway.
```

config file in DEBIAN/ directory-

```
#!/bin/sh
 
# Exit on error
set -e

. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
db_input low gateway/input1 || true

db_go || true
```

However, when I try to install the package, it extracts the package and terminates the installation without asking for any user input.